# Can I apply X-Frame-Options header and people still use <iframe> with my website

Tags: html, iframe, http-headers, x-frame-options

I want to add this header to my nginx server

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
```

However I want people to still be able to use an `<iframe>` that refers to my website.

Like youtube provides an embeded url for video, I do the same for a particular part of my website.

is `"SAMEORIGIN"` is the right value? or is `X-Frame-Options` header is in conflict with the functionality I'm trying to acheive?

Answer (score 3):

There are three possible directives for `X-Frame-Options`:

- `X-Frame-Options: deny` page cannot be displayed in a frame
- `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself (same domain)
- `X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com/` page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin

If you set it at `sameorigin` when hosts(people) try to load your site in an `<iframe>` then the browser give you an error. Try this and open your dev console:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com"/>
```

So in short `sameorigin` of course is the wrong choice if you want your site to be loaded into an `<iframe>` by other people(domains). Try reading this if you want to get what you are looking for:

[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Comment: is there a value for X-Frame-Options: allow-from that allow all domain? like allow-from *

Comment: allow-from is no longer suppurated  by Chrome and Firefox so you need use another header "Content-Security-Policy"

Comment: if you want to load certain pages of your site in iframe you can use a proxy page that load the content you want or you can override the header for certain page, read the link above, there are different solutions

Comment: I have Content-Security-Policy set. Then I guess I will do without this header.